# Difference between return $something; vs return $this->something

Tags: php, class, oop, getter-setter

I am currently learning object oriented concepts in PHP. and I found some examples for getter and setter methods:

**example1:**

```
class UserModel{

    private $id,$name,$email;

    public function __construct(){}

    public function setid($id){
        $this->id=$id;      
    }   
    public function getid(){
        return $this->id;       
    }

    public function setname($name){
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    public function getname(){
        return $this->name;
    }       

    public function setemail($email) {
        $this->email=$email;
    }
    public function getemail() {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

**example2:**

```
class UserModel{

    private $id,$name,$email;

    public function __construct(){}

    public function setid($id){
        $this->id=$id;      
    }   
    public function getid(){
        return $id;     
    }

    public function setname($name){
        $this->name=$name;
    }
    public function getname(){
        return $name;
    }       

    public function setemail($email) {
        $this->email=$email;
    }
    public function getemail() {
        return $email;
    }
}
```

As you can notice, in first example, in getter methods, `$this->property` is  returned. and in second, `$property` is returned.

[From manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), I knew about $this that it will always have reference of invoking object, so in this case, `$this->property` will ensure that it will return only property of invoking object. But, as in first example, `return $property` should also have the reference of invoking object.

For example if I write:

```
UserModel $user = new UserModel();
$user->setemail("example@so.com");
$user->getemail();
```

then, in both examples, getter method will always have reference of UserModel object. So, are they both same or different? if they are different, then what is the difference between them? Can anyone explain if both work differently in different scenarios?

Sorry but I'm new to OOP. please help guys.

Comment: A variable like `$email` is like any other PHP variable, and is scoped only to the function/method in which it is defined, so `public function getemail() {
        return $email;
    }
` can only ever return null, because `$email` isn't defined/set anywhere in the function where it is used, so it is never assigned any value

Comment: @MarkBaker so if I access getemail() without prior using setemail(...) in second example, then it will show error. am I right?

Comment: No, `setemail()` sets `$this->email`, not `$email`.... and even if it did set `$email` it simply be a local variable scoped to the `setemail()` method, not accessible outside of that method.... standard PHP scope rules apply to all local variables, even in classes...... it's the use of class properties (referenced via the classname and the `::` operator) or instance properties (referenced via `$this` and the `->` operator) that are different

Comment: PHP is not like Java or C++ - `this` is not included in the name resolution chain, therefore `$foo` is just `$foo`, not implicit `$this->foo`.

Comment: @georg oh...ya that should be the correct answer. I wondered because I had some experience in Java. Can you explain better in answer? I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a name (identifier) in your program, the compiler/interpreter needs to obtain its value. To do that, it consults its internal table of name=>value pairs, called "scope". If the name is not found in the current scope, it consults another scope, if possible, until there are no more scopes to look in - in which case, it shouts at you complaining that the name is undefined. This process is called "name resolution" and scopes are linked together in a "scope chain".

I don't know Java, but I think its name resolution looks like this:

- when you see a (simple) name, like `foo`, ...
- look if it was declared in the current block
- if this fails, look in outer blocks, until we reach the class level
- look in the class declaration if there's a field with this name
- if this fails, look further (package etc)

So when you write `foo` in your code, and there's no local variable `foo`, Java will look for a field named `foo`.

PHP's resolution rules are different and much simpler:

- when you see `$foo`...
- look if it's declared in the current function as `global`
- if yes, it's a global name, otherwise - a local name

As you can see, class declaration is not included in the scope chain, therefore `$foo` will never refer to a field - it's always a variable. That's why you always have to use explicit `$this->` when referring to object fields.

PHP is not unique in this regard - other scripting languages use explicit `this` too (`self.foo`, `@foo`) and the reason for this is that these languages don't have declarations, so when you have `foo=1` it would be impossible for the compiler to decide if you're assigning a new value to a field or introducing a new local variable.

Comment: though, PHP's rules are the worst. aren't hey?

Comment: @xyz: as I said, PHP is not unique here, other scripting languages use the same system.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, `return $email;` returns an undefined variable, or in other words: that will not work. The reverence to the UserModel object is the `$this` variable. You always need to use `$this` if you want to access a class method or property.

Comment: But when I use $user->getemail(); the, it will automatically assign to $user object. Can you explain whether $this is required or not?

Comment: No, you don't assing the `$user` object like this. `$user` is assinged in this line: `$user = new UserModel();` When calling the getter method, the object stays unchanged, it just returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight difference in the two statements:

```
$this->$something;
```

The above statement means that a variable i.e $something is returned that is the part of the object of the current class. `&this` in the statement means the current pointer or reference of the current class and the variable in that reference is returned.

```
$something
```

In the above statement a normal variable containing any value is used.

Comment: but isn't is true that while calling getter method, $something will also have value for invoking object reference?

Comment: this is not always necessary and the second benefit of using $this is that it passes the value of the variable from its own reference that means that no extra memory is required.

Answer (score 0):

"This" is a reference to the variable of "this" class you are working on.

So, return $something will not work for you. It will return null.
While $this->something will return the value of the variable of this class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply it's a way to reference variables in the object. The variables you create in body of class are called attributes of object and to access them you need to reference the object they belong to. Since you don't know what object variable will be called that's why you need to use $this->variable where $this is a pseudo-variable.

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object).

Then there are local variables you can use only in body of function.

```
class Test {

    private $attribute; //This attribute can be used in methods by using $this->attribute

    function testFunction() {
        $local; //This variable can be used only in this function
    }

}
```

And about your question. In your example 2 of UserModel the method getemail() returns local variable which is fine as long as it's defined, but won't return attribute $email.